# Levenshtein distance for non-english languages

Tags: string, levenshtein-distance

Which other languages besides English does Levenshtein distance support its implementation?

I know that the language needs to have single-character based representation (and not two or more characters being treated as a single entity like in Dutch?), and wanted to know which languages fall/do not fall in this category.

Thanks
Abhishek S

Comment: This is clearly off-topic, it's a question about natural languages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Levenshtein distance is defined on arbitrary strings, in the mathematical sense; it is not language-specific. You should just make sure you're computing it on the right level of representation, the sensible default being the level of Unicode code points after some [normalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_equivalence#Normalization). If the language you're handling always needs two symbols to represent anything meaningful, then compute Levenshtein distance on pairs of symbols.

[I'm not sure what you mean by multiple characters being "a single entity" in Dutch but if you mean the [*ij* ligature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IJ_%28digraph%29), that has never stopped me from applying Levenshtein to Dutch text :)]